# Find eigenvalues of A knowing its trace and the eigenvalues of $A^2+2A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$ be a diagonalizable matrix with $\mathbf{trace}$($A$) = $-4$.
Let {$-1$, $3$, $8$} be the eigenvalues of $A^2+2A$.
Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

I tried stating that the sum of eigenvalues for $A$ has to be $-4$, which is also the coefficient for $\lambda^2$ in $\chi_{A}(\lambda)$ (minus a sign), but it has gotten me nowhere. Also I don't know how to work the part about the eigenvalues of $A^2+2A$.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Comment: The information on the trace seems useless. When $A$ is diagonizable , if $\lambda(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$, $P(\lambda(A))$ is the set of eigenvalues of $P(A)$. (P is a polynomial)

Comment: @PierreCarre The information on the trace *is* needed.

Comment: @egregg I misread the question... I was thinking in terms of obtaining the eigenvalues of $A^2+2A$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2+2A$ tells you that $\det(A^2+2A+I)=0$, hence that $\det(A+I)=0$, because $A^2+2A+I=(A+I)^2$.

In particular $-1$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Next $\det(A^2+2A-3I)=0$, leading to $\det(A+3I)\det(A-I)=0$; also $\det(A^2+2A-8I)=0$, leading to $\det(A+4I)\det(A-2I)=0$.

Thus we have four possibilities: the remaining two eigenvalues, besides $-1$, can be
$$
-3,-4\quad\text{or}\quad
-3,2,\quad\text{or}\quad
1,-4,\quad\text{or}\quad
1,2
$$
Since we know that the trace of $A$ is $-4$…

The information that $A$ is diagonalizable is irrelevant.

Comment: You should replace $3$ by $-3$.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is less general than the one proposed by @egreg but, considering that the assumption that $A$ is diagonizable was included, it might be closer to the expected answer. If $\lambda(A) = \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$, since $A$ is diagonizable, the set of eigenvalues of $P(A)=A^2+2A$ is $\lambda (P(A)) = \{\lambda_1^2 + 2 \lambda_1, \lambda_2^2+2 \lambda_2, \lambda_3^2+2 \lambda_3 \}$. Since you know that $\lambda(P(A))=\{-1,3,8\}$, you can conclude that
$$
\lambda_1^2+2 \lambda_1 = -1, \quad \lambda_2^2+2\lambda_2 = 3, \quad \lambda_3^3+2 \lambda_3 = 8,
$$

therefore you have that $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=-3$ or $1$ and $\lambda_3 =-4$ or $2$. Since the trace is $-4$ (and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues), the only way is if $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=-4$.

Comment: The requirement that $A$ is diagonalizable is not necessary: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2+\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2+A$. Since $A^2+A$ has three distinct eigenvalues, also $A$ must.

Comment: @egreg I understood your solution. As I mentioned, this answer is less general, I only posted it because in standard linear algebra courses the relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $P(A)$ is normally established for diagonizable matrices.